# Custom widget setVisibilty method doesn't work?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-mediaplayer

I have made a custom widget which plays a audio from url. I make use of MediaPlayer API.

The way the widget has been implemented:

```
    public class CustomAudioPayer extends RelativeLayout {

        ....
        public CustomAudioPayer(final Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
                super(context, attrs);
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_palyer, this, true);

        // Code to initialize player & set url
        .......
        // On button click, we start playing

        play_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        showProgressBar(true);
         mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                if (headers != null) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), uri, headers);
.....

        mediaPlayer.prepare();

.....
        }
        }
        }
    ...........
    }
```

But when the media player buffering the stream from the server, I make one progress bar visible, The progress bar visible & invisible based on player state & buffer listener.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int what) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate");
                switch (what) {
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START:
                        showProgressBar(true);
                        break;
                    case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END:
                        showProgressBar(false);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

But the initial progress bar visible doesn't reflect ASAP in the widget. i.e. When the media player is querying content from the server at that time none of the setVisibility method work on the progress bar.

The showProgressBar(boolean) method:

```
private void showProgressBar(boolean show) {
        if (show) {
            buffering_pb.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            Log.e(TAG, "buffering_pb: Visible");
        } else {
            buffering_pb.setVisibility(INVISIBLE);
            Log.e(TAG, "buffering_pb: Invisible");
        }
    }
```

The logs added in above method gets printed on logcat ASAP they go visible or invisible but UI doesn't show the respective visibility change, What may go wrong?

**Update:**

User [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473348/custom-widget-setvisibilty-method-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment91888651_52473348) in comments suggested documentation of [MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync()) instead of `MediaPlayer.prepare();`, I changed the method from `prepare()` to `prepareAsyc()` then my views are reflecting the visible & invisible state immediatly.

Comment: are you calling `MediaPlayer#prepare()`?

Comment: @pskink yes I am, plz have look at the updated question

Comment: see `MediaPlayer#prepareAsync()` method documentation

Comment: @pskink, Thanks for comment this solved my issue UI is responsive with prepareAsycn() please post this as the answer I will mark as solved.